# I would like to be able to link to comments on the election nomination page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, election

For some reason, unlike every other page on the site, there are no built-in links to comments on [the nomination page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).

[image]

I'm not sure if it's a bug that the links aren't showing up, or if was an intentional decision, but it would be useful to be able to link to these when discussion things with candidates in chat.

Comment: Also: If you manually create the link by appending #comment-id to the URL, it still doesn't onebox in chat :(

Comment: @StrixVaria That really is the bigger problem. Grabbing the id for the link isn't all that much an issue and can probably be UserScript'd.

Comment: [Speaking of which.](http://vad-systems.de/projects/stack/userscripts/election.user.js)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

With the [recent updates to the election system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979/179041), election comments now share the same functionality with their main site counterparts:

> #### Ability to flag nominations and comments
>
> ...We also added standard commenting functionality to the Elections page. You can now upvote comments, flag comments and link directly to comments.